# Optimize distribution of buffers

Tags: buffer, network, optimization

I'm currently moving from using QGIS more as a visual tool to an analytical one. I am hoping to get better at optimal location distribution.

I have a dataset of census population data visualized as a shapefile. I'd like to optimally distribute buffer circles across the U.S. to maximize the capture of population within each buffer. So far, it looks like most plugins require a start point for a buffer and calculations are completed around that point. I'd like to flip that so that data determines which point to select.

How would I go about setting something like this up?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to the 'dataset of census population data visualized as a shapefile'? What does that mean / look like, and what type of data is it (point, etc.)?

Comment: This is [Openshaw's Optimal bombing strategy](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0260982782900143) - there are papers out there that discuss how to solve it e.g. https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/10.1080/13658810500032388